# Ionic 5 - NativeAudio

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor, ionic5

I have a problem with the IONIC plugin NativeAudio.
I'm using IONIC with Capacitor with this configuration

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.26
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.26
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.26
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 2.0.1
   @capacitor/core : 2.0.1

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : not installed
   native-run (update available: 1.0.0) : 0.2.8

System:

   NodeJS : v13.11.0 (/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.11.0/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.13.7
   OS     : macOS Catalina
```

I install the Plugin as described in the DOC.

This is my sound service.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform} from '@ionic/angular';
import {NativeAudio} from '@ionic-native/native-audio/ngx';

const INCREASE = 'increase_audio';
const DECREASE = 'decrease_audio';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SoundService {

  private isSoundPlaying: boolean;
  private isAudioAvailable: boolean;

  constructor(
    private nativeAudio: NativeAudio,
    private platform: Platform
  ) {
    this.isSoundPlaying = false;
    this.isAudioAvailable = false;
    if (platform.is('hybrid')) {
      this.isAudioAvailable = true;
      this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple(INCREASE, 'sounds/increase.mp3').catch();
      this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple(DECREASE, 'sounds/decrease.mp3').catch();
    }
  }

  playIncrease() {
    this.playSound(INCREASE);
  }

  playDecrease() {
    this.playSound(DECREASE);
  }

  private playSound(soundId: string) {
    this.isSoundPlaying = true;
    if (!this.isSoundPlaying && this.isAudioAvailable) {
      this.nativeAudio.play(soundId).then(() => {
        this.isSoundPlaying = false;
      }, () => {
        this.isSoundPlaying = false;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I inject it in a "controller" where I want to play the little sound.
I don't inject anything in the app module, because is not reported in the documentation but I also try to put `NativeAudio` in the provider array but it still not working.

The error is :  **NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NativeAudio]**

As you can see in the image in attached.

[image]

Thanks to all can help me, regards

Comment: Add NativeAudio at app.module.ts in providers section and and will be solved.

Comment: Is ionic-native package installed on the project? Ionic native setup -> https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/community

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic5, following works. Need "/ngx".

app.module.ts

```
import { NativeAudio } from '@ionic-native/native-audio/ngx';

...

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [..., NativeAudio],
  ...
})
```

Note that in the latest capacitor( as of June 2021 ), assets are located under public folder not in www folder, then we will see an error from NativeAudio module that assets are not found. I had to rewrite the folder path as per https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/2685.